# jquery mobile make custom element focusable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

im using jquery mobile for the styling and structure of my web page and um using angular.js with angular-touch.js for my javascript framework. ive come accross a problem with jquery mobile i have a `<canvas></canvas>` element that i want to be focusable like a text box. without jquery mobile i can just add `tabindex='1'` to the element attributes and that works but once i insert it into jquery mobile something stops it from being focusable anymore. Does anyone know how to make an element focusable in jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out that running the `.focus()` function on an element makes it focusable when using jquery even with jquery mobile so it would either look like this

```
$('element').focus();
```

or since im using angular it looks like this

```
angular.element('element').focus();
```